# Bolding and Italics

Tags: php, regex, formatting, preg-replace

I want to achieve what stack overflow does, so you can do `_italics_` and `*bold*` and it changes it to `<em>italics</em>` and `<strong>bold</strong>`, however, I'm a beginner to regex, and i'm having a hard time writing the regex replace for this.

Thanks in advance ->
Will

Answer (score 7, accepted):

StackOverflow uses [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) to transform the syntax you reference (and more!) to HTML markup. You'd be wise to use this framework, or one like it, rather than rolling your own - why go to all that effort to reproduce something that works well?

> Markdown is a text-to-HTML conversion tool for web writers. Markdown allows you to write using an easy-to-read, easy-to-write plain text format, then convert it to structurally valid XHTML (or HTML).

If you do decide to roll your own, use something besides regular expressions, like a [state machine](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-python-state.html) - regular expressions will get complicated very quickly for task of this complexity.